# Simplify Ricci tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, general-relativity, kronecker-delta

Given a Ricci tensor $$R_{kk} = -(g_{kk})/a^2 - \delta_{ki}\delta_{ik}g_{kk}/a^2 + \delta_{jk}\delta_{ik}g_{kk}/a^2 + \delta_{ki}\delta_{ik}g_{kk}/a^2.$$

What's its correct simplified form? Here's my trial:
$$a^2R_{kk} = -g_{kk} - n g_{kk} + \delta_{ij}g_{kk} + ng_{kk}\\
= -g_{kk} +\delta_{ij}g_{kk}.$$

From the result above, I see that $R_{kk} = 0$ for $i=j$ and $R_{kk} = -g_{kk}/a^2$ for $i\neq j$. Should I assume that, when $i=j$, $\delta_{ij} = n$, where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold?

I know it may look trivial for some of you, but I'm starting into General relativity and these manipulations with tensors and the einstein sum convention is still confusing to me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your fomrula for $R_{kk}$ does not quite make sense. Why is there no $i, j$ on the left hand side?

Comment: I don’t recognize any of these formulas. The Ricci tensor formula contains first and second derivatives of the metric tensor.